# convergence of sum $\sum_{r=1}^\infty\log(r)\frac{\log\bigl(1+\frac{1}{r(r+2)}\bigr)}{\log 2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove that the following series is convergent:

$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\log(r)\frac{\log\bigl(1+\frac{1}{r(r+2)}\bigr)}{\log 2}$

I'm trying to use the criterion of the comparison, but I do not think I'm comparing correctly because it diverges every time. Any tips?

Comment: Apply the relation $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = 1$  to the second logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *equivalents*:
$$\log\biggl(1+\frac1{r(r+2)}\biggr)\sim_\infty \frac1{r(r+2)}\sim_\infty \frac1{r^2},\quad\text{so }\quad \log r\,\frac{\log\bigl(1+\frac{1}{r(r+2)}\bigr)}{\log 2}\sim_\infty \frac1{\log 2}\frac{\log r}{r^2},$$
and $\;\displaystyle\sum_{r\ge 1}\frac{\log r}{r^2}$ is a convergent *Bertrand's series*.

Comment: It comes from Taylor's formla at order $1$: near $u=0$, we have  $\;\ln(1+u)=u+o(u)$, so $\;\ln(1+u)\sim_0 u$.

Comment: Thank you!  I just understood